# How to find ETH txid by value and date?

Tags: etherscan

How to find ETH transaction txid by value and date ?
Smth like Blockchair, but for ETH ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Find ETH txid by date

Currently there is no tool to do so. You can randomly guess which block would would have been issued when. As each block is issued [roughly](https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime) every 15 seconds.

Or a smarter way would be to compute it:

```
blocksPerSecond = 15s
oldTime = /*timestamp in seconds of the time you want to search about*/
now = currentTimeStamp
duration = now-oldTime

requiredBlock = currentBlock - duration/blocksPerSecond
```

But still, there would be some discrepancy, as our blocksPerSecond is a rough estimate.

#### Find ETH txid by value

This is a more intensive process, and it also has no tool available. For this info, you need to process each block and get the required data.

---

However, http://etherscan.io provides various types of [charts](https://etherscan.io/charts) with some information that may be interesting to you.